# Angular 4 primeng Autocomlete doesn't show selected value

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

I'm implementing an autocomplete (primeng) to perform a city suggestions.
my suggestions are objects with name, region, province etc....
But I need to bind to a string.

When I select some of the suggestions proposed I see the correct value into my variable but I can't see nothing in the autocomplete field.
selected. city is a string with city name, cities is the object array

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selected.city" [suggestions]="cities"
                    field="name" delay=500 (completeMethod)="searchCity($event)"
                    (onSelect)="setCity($event)"
                    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control">

                <ng-template let-city pTemplate="item">
                <div class="ui-helper-clearfix"
                    style="border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5">
                    <div style="font-size: 15px; float: left; margin: 2px 2px 0 0">{{city.name}}
                        ({{city.province}})</div>
                    <div style="font-size: 12px; float: left; margin: 3px 3px 0 0">{{city.region}}</div>
                </div>
                </ng-template></p-autoComplete>
```

in the component I have:

```
cities: City[];
selected: Customer;

getCustomerDetail(code) {

    this.http.get(EndpointUrlService.baseUrl + code)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.selected = response.json() as Customer;
      });
  }

  setCity(event) {
    this.selected.city = event.name;
  }

  searchCity(event) {

    this.customerService.getCities(event.query)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.cities = response._embedded.cities.name as City[];
      });
  }
```

**city.ts**

```
export class City {

  'sid': string;
  'createdDate': any;
  'lastModifiedDate': any;
  'lastModifiedBy': string;
  'name': string;
  'province': string;
  'region': string;

}
```

**customer.ts**

```
export class Customer {

  'address': string;
  'balance': number;
  'city': string;
  'createdDate': any;
  'iban': string;
  'landlinePhone': string;
  'lastModifiedBy': string;
  'lastModifiedDate': string;
  'mobilePhone': string;
  'movements': string;
  'name': string;
  'new': boolean;
  'sid': string;
  'swift': string;
  'taxCode': string;
  'username': string;
}
```

Comment: Add you `component.ts` code and a sample object from `cities` in your question

Comment: response edited @Nehal

Comment: primeng document says using property 'field' will display only that field of object in selection like this `<p-autoComplete .. field="name"` will display only city name. have you tried that? else check if `<ng-template let-value pTemplate="selectedItem">` works for you.